# Right way of deserialization of json array into model using gson,retrofit

Tags: retrofit2, rx-java2, android, gson

I use gson for deserializing http response(which comes from retrofit) into model. So, now I have some json array as response, like this:

```
[{"object":"value"},{"object":"value"},{"object":"value"},{"object":"value"}]
```

By combining rxjava and retrofit, I make http request and try to save response in my model as shown in code below:

```
    @GET("contacts")
    Observable<ResponseModel> getBankDepartments();
```

So **question** is how should I use gson to save reponse in this model.
Usually in simple json responses like this `{"status":1}`I use

```
@SerializedName("status")
@Expose
```

annotations for specific field. But how I'll do the same for json array? 
**P.S** If smth is wrong in grammar or smth else, pls don't blame)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to save array you can just return `Observable<List<ResponseModel>>` instead of single object.